# Setting mouse cursor position in visual studio on a mac

Tags: c#, macos, winforms

I'm an experienced windows/c sharp developer and am trying to write my first mac based program using visual studio for mac. I want to basically use this code:

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
```

However there is no System.Windows.Forms reference to add and so wondering how you can use this functionality on a mac?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop WinForms on OSX you should look into this:

1. [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/)
2. [Porting into Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/porting-winforms-applications/)